# Sorting javascript arrays by [field] values gives wrong order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm implementing SlickGrid and I want to allow sorting of values by columns, which is supported by SlickGrid by sorting arrays, however, when I sort the columns (arrays) they are not put in the "correct" order.

The order in which they are returned is 1,10,100,11,199,2,20,200,3,30,300....

The problem is displayed very clearly when trying to sort the tasks in this grid by title:
http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-multi-column-sort.html

Although I use my own sorting rule, instead of the one used in the example:

```
data.sort(function(a, b){
          var result = 
              a[field] === b[field] ? 0 :
              a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1
          ; 
          return args.sortAsc ? result : -result;
      });
```

The problem persists.

My question is merely how to sort the array, so that the title (and other data) will be displayed in the correct order: 1,2,3,100,200,300...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your numbers are actually strings and will be compared as such. To prevent this, use `parseInt(a[field],10) > parseInt(b[field],10)`

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was the case, however, Won't I get in trouble if I parse a string to an int, and it contains letters?

Comment: You can have another argument that specifies whether you want to handle the input as number or letters, or do some detection work (if `/^\d+$/` matches then it's a number)

Comment: Thanks! That regex was exactly the glue I needed. The fact that the function does not sort strings containing numbers correctly can be accepted, so I converted the numerical strings to ints before comparing them. Hope this helps someone else. `      if (/^\d*$/.test(a[field]) && /^\d*$/.test(b[field]))
      {
        a[field] = parseInt(a[field], 10)
        b[field] = parseInt(b[field], 10)
      }
`

Answer (score 2):

if you are just trying to sort objects of the same type, then there is no problem... your algorithm seems right.

but it seems that your numbers might be actually strings, so they are sorted as strings.
you can parse them into numbers .. ie `parseInt() , parseFloat()` etc.

But if the field is a string followed by a number like the example in the link, then it will not work

`"data 20"` will always be less than `"data 3"`, so you might want to extract the number then sort by both the string and the number.